# Colours of tikzpicture are appearing differently in different apps

Tags: tikz-pgf, color

> **Disclaimer:** Honestly, I do not know whether this is the forum to ask this question. But since I do not know the appropriate forum, I am
> asking it here. If anybody can suggest the proper forum, that will
> also help.

Please refer to the following code snippet.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
    \fill [fill=green!30] (0,0) -- (3,0) -- (3.5,2) -- (0.5,2) -- cycle;
    \fill [fill=green!30, opacity=50] (0,0) rectangle (3,2);
    \fill [fill=blue!80, opacity=50] (0,0) -- (3,0) -- (2.5,2) -- cycle;
    \draw [black, dashed] (2.5,2) -- (2.5,0) node[midway, right] {$ h $};
    \draw (0,0) -- (3,0) node [midway, below] {$ b $};          
\end{tikzpicture}
```

This is to illustrate the formula for the area of a triangle. The colours in this image are displayed differently in different apps. I am using a MacBook Air (13-inch, Early 2015) with the Built-in Display which says "13.3-inch (1440 x 900)" and "Intel HD Graphics 6000 1536 MB graphics" in its description. The default `Preview` app is displaying the image like this:

[image]

whereas the `Adobe Acrobat Reader` app is displaying the colours like:

[image]

`Preview` is not displaying the `blue` colour properly but is respecting the opacity. Whereas `Adobe Acrobat Reader` is doing exactly the other way. What is the reason for this? I suspect this has something to do with *colour accuracy*. But can an app have issues with colour accuracy? Isn't that an issue with screens only? Please enlighten me.

**EDIT:** As requested, the following is an MWE.

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169,10pt, notheorems]{beamer}
\setbeamerfont{headline}{size=\fontsize{8}{0}\selectfont}
\setbeamerfont{footline}{size=\fontsize{6}{0}\selectfont}
\usetheme{CambridgeUS}
\usefonttheme{serif}
\usecolortheme{beetle}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=black}
\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=white}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
            \fill [fill=green!30] (0,0) -- (3,0) -- (3.5,2) -- (0.5,2) -- cycle;
            \fill [fill=green!30, opacity=50] (0,0) rectangle (3,2);
            \fill [fill=blue!80, opacity=50] (0,0) -- (3,0) -- (2.5,2) -- cycle;
            \draw [black, dashed] (2.5,2) -- (2.5,0) node[midway, right] {$ h $};
            \draw (0,0) -- (3,0) node [midway, below] {$ b $};          
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have added an MWE.

Comment: You should use a value between 0 and 1 for the opacity, so instead of `50` use `0.5`.

Comment: sometimes, `Preview` does not give exact colors, line width, etc (as the name Preview ^^). Your code look good in Acrobat , so that is okay. A bit change of your code `\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\fill[green!30] (0,0)--(3,0) node [midway,below,white]{$b$}--(3.5,2)-- (0.5,2)--cycle;
\fill[green!30,opacity=.5] (0,0) rectangle (3,2);
\fill[blue!80,opacity=.5] (0,0)--(3,0)-- (2.5,2)--cycle;
\draw[dashed] (2.5,2)--(2.5,0) node[midway,right]{$h$};
\end{tikzpicture}
`